# How to scroll screen down automatically when text cursor is out of visible area in android jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In Android View System, when cursor(cursor of EditText view in ScrollView) is out of visible area, Android automatically scroll screen to down to make cursor always visible.

[image: EditText in ScrollView]

Is there way to achieve this in android Jetpack Compose?

BasicTextField in LazyColumn seems to not support this behavior basically.

[image: BasicTextField in LazyColumn]

+)

Here is a composable codes sample that can regenerate this issue.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    var content by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
    ) {
        val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 15.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            item {
                BasicTextField(
                    value = content,
                    onValueChange = { content = it },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = Color.Green)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.test">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Test">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Test"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share your composables that contains the TextField which you use ? You should share it in largest scale, I mean composable that contains this TextField and top of the UI hierarchy.(e.g ProfileScreen)

Comment: @SevbanBayır, I edited my question so you can now see the code which can regenerate issue I told in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do the scrolling manually, on each change in the text field. First you need to set vertical scroll modifier and use the state to scroll down for amount of pixel equal to the line height.

```
@Composable
fun SelfScrollingTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    value: TextFieldValue,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    onValueChanged: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit
) {
    val scroll = rememberScrollState()
    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.verticalScroll(scroll)),
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChanged
    )
    LaunchedEffect(value) {
        scroll.animateScrollTo(textStyle.lineHeight.value.toInt())
    }
}
```

The `LaunchEffect` will be triggered as soon as input has changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an extension to calculate what line the cursor are by `TextFieldValue` as above:

```kotlin
val TextFieldValue.selectionLine: Int 
    get() = text.take(selection.start).count { it == '\n' } + 1
```

and use as following:

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
var textFieldValue by remember {
    mutableStateOf(value = TextFieldValue())
}

Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    topBar = { AppBar(onNavigationIconClick = navigateUp) },
) { padding ->
    val textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.copy(
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
    )
    val lineHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        textStyle.lineHeight.value.dp.roundToPx()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = textFieldValue) {
        scrollState.animateScrollTo(value = (textFieldValue.selectionLine - 1) * lineHeight)
    }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(state = scrollState),
        value = textFieldValue,
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it },
        textStyle = textStyle,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = padding),
            ) {
                innerTextField()
            }
        }
    )
}
```